# jQuery Get value from class attribute of multiple elements in array without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have multiple Select dropdown elements with a single class `.select`

```
<select class='select' name='select1' id='select1'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<select class='select' name='select2' id='select2'>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
  <option value='5'>5</option>
  <option value='6'>6</option>
</select>

<select class='select' name='select3' id='select3'>
  <option value='7'>7</option>
  <option value='8'>8</option>
  <option value='9'>9</option>
</select>
```

I know it can be achieved with the help of loop like this

```
var arr = [];
$('.select').each(function () {
   arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

But I already have so many loops in the code and I'm wondering if is there any way it can be achievable without a loop

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89cJC/

Comment: Any implementation will have loop for this :) You cant avoid

Answer (score 14):

No, there's no other way to get the value from multiple elements, you have to iterate over the elements to get the value from each of them.

There are other ways to write basically the same code

```
var arr = $.map($('.select'), function (el) { return el.value; });
```

or without jQuery

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.select'),
    arr   = [];

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) arr.push(elems[i].value);
```

but they all iterate, there's no other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **$.map** function of jquery to deal with elements array

for example

```
var arr = [];
arr = $.map($(".select"),function(select){
        return $(select).val();
});

console.log(arr);
```