# Get specific elements from arrays within array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am having some trouble with getting what I want out of jQuery.
I have an ajax call that returns and array of arrays.

my jQuery looks something like this...

```
$.each(search_results, function()
{
  $.each(this, function(results)
  {
    var first_name = '';
    var last_name = '';
    $.each(this, function(index, value)
    {
      if(index == 3 )
      {
        last_name = value;
      }

      if(index == 5)
      {
        first_name = value;
        var contact_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
        var result_item = '<li class="list-group-item">' + contact_name + '</li>';
          $(id).append(result_item);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This works and is all well and good, but I'm returning hundreds of records.
Looping through each element in the array to pickout two to five elements seems like WAY too much work.

Is there a way to do something like this...

```
  $.each(search_results, function()
{
  $.each(this, function(results)
  {
    $.each(this, function(result)
    {
       var first_name = result[5];
       var last_name = result[3];
        var contact_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
        var result_item = '<li class="list-group-item">' + contact_name + '</li>';
          $(id).append(result_item);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507881/jquery-get-value-from-class-attribute-of-multiple-elements-in-array-without-loop), but the answer seems odd to me. There has to be a way....

I hope this helps more

Array / JSON Structure:

```
Object { search_results: […] }
search_results : Array [ […], […], […], … ]
[0..99]
0 : Array [ "all", "stuff", "I want", … ]
```

Comment: Are you going one level too far - there's 3 each calls in a 2D array

Comment: I know I found it odd I had to go that deep, something about how my json gets returned. The first piece of code works, which tells me that is in fact the array I want. I hope it's that simple, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I don't really see what the question is - can you explain? You're missing `var` (or `const`, `let`) before first_name and last_name by the way

Comment: Why use jQuery at all for array manipulation? `$.each(search_results` is the same as `search_results.forEach(`

Comment: @JeremyThille My question is how do I access a specific element of an array. If i have 50 elements and I only want 3 I'd like to say I want array[3] array[5] and array[7]. rather than looping through all 50 elements.

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley I removed a level, I just get undefined values in both cases

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Of course array[3] should work, why wouldn't it?

Comment: That's what I thought... I don't know why it wouldn't/won't work. it seems correct to me.

Comment: What output / error are you getting?

Comment: I guess I can't show a screen shot, but my list just populates all the values as 'undefined'. No actual error message.

Comment: Do you know the contents of the array at each stage? Do a `console.log` for results and result. The only reason that they would be undefined would be that they are not actually in the array at that position

Comment: It logs a list of numbers, which I assume are all the indexes from each array.

Comment: If I remove a `$.each` statement, it returns more indexes, but much less. I believe these are the indexes of the parent array.

Comment: @gregnnylf94 `My question is how do I access a specific element of an array` --> Yes, I got that. What does it have to do with my comment about not needing jQuery for manipulating arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you have an array similar to:

```
 var search_results = [
                         [
                            [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5], 
                            [2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]
                         ]
                      ];
```

And you want to access elements 1.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2.5....

Following code will access those elements.

```
$.each(search_results, function(l1_index, l1_result)
{
   $.each(this, function(l2_index, l2_result)
   {
     if(l2_result.length > 5)
     {
         var last_name = l2_result[3];
         var first_name = l2_result[5];
         var contact_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
         var result_item = '<li class="list-group-item">' + contact_name + '</li>';
         $(id).append(result_item);
     }
  });
});
```

P.S: If you can post your array structure everyone can better understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I still have the similar issue though. So now my list didn't populate. This kind of tells me I'm at the wrong level because of the if statement.

Comment: @gregnnylf94 If you want to display all of your records, you have to iterate through all of them. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: That's seems crazy to me. The issue is  that I am returning a list of 100's of records, each of which has 30 elements in the array. I DO NOT want to loop over 300 + elements to get 60-90 values. It takes way to long on the user side. I just want to grab array[3] array[5] and possible array[50] for example. I do not have the option of limiting my array to just those elements either... (unless I loop through them and put them in another array, even worse)

Comment: @gregnnylf94: Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Yes you are, thank you. I have added the data structure to the question. I'm looking at this code snippet now.

Comment: " _The issue is that I am returning a list of 100's of records, each of which has 30 elements in the array. I DO NOT want to loop over 300 + elements to get 60-90 values_ " Perhaps you can limit the array when returning it from the server ... saves the time to fetch data + no client side filtering required.

Comment: @DipenShah YES! Thank you! So I guess I don't understand, `$.each` returns an index and the object? So I kept just grabbing the index and trying to access and element in the index...

Comment: @KarelG That's not really an option for me. My page is mostly jQuery and I DO need those values, just not right away. I am new to jQuery so if there is a better way please point in a direction. Thank you all for the help.